# How to reroute a DDoS attack to the attacker?

Tags: domain-name-system, ddos, cloudflare

I would like to know if there is a way to block and reroute a DDoS attack I'm receiving on my website to the attacker website (I know the address of it).

If so, how can I do that? I'm using CloudFlare and I was thinking to make it reroute all the requests to the attacker IP but I don't technically know how do it. Can someone give me an hand? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not sure if it's a efficient way of dealing with incoming DDoS. Besides legal issues. You can't say  "I break in his house, because he broke in mine". Nevertheless it would be awesome to send all that data back ;-)

Comment: The problem is that there isn't one attacker.  DDOS is Distributed DOS -- there may be hundreds or thousands of attackers.  Almost all of them are innocent 3rd parties.

Answer (score 4):

Besides from legal issues, this is not possible technically. DDoS attacks are initiated from too many machines. You can not return that traffic from your single or few server(s).

[DDoS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) are triggered from one machine towards many other machines (possibly exploited by attacker) which then send too many requests to destination (victim). How can this be returned to attacker?

Instead, you can try to limit traffic and block suspicious IPs using any of the available tools depending on the type of attack and affected service(s).